# uniq + not get uniq strings from file

Tags: bash

Please take a look on the following
all I want is to get the node_name string from the file and perform uniq to get uniq strings if they equal

but on the following example I have two equal lines ( node_name moon1 )

but why uniq command not decrease it to one line??? , I am really not understand this why?

```
 sed s'/=/ /'g file|  awk -v WORD=node_name '$2 == WORD {print $0}' | awk '{print $2" "$3}' | sort | uniq

 node_name moon1
 node_name moon1
```

the file:

```
  .
  .

 /home/home1/home2/config1/COMPANY/my.config      node_name=moon1
 /home/home1/home2/config1/MEAS2XML/my.config.tmp node_name=moon1

  .
  .
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://www.ideone.com/HYkDH

Comment: the file have more then 1000 lines the two lines are part of the big file

Comment: hi I find ^M after moon1 - please advice how to remove this

Comment: @jon if you have the dos2unix command on your system, running it against your file is the easiest way to remove ^M characters.

Comment: did U suggest to run tr -d \r on the file or in the line?

Comment: @jon: Filtering the file through tr -d '\r' will remove the extra line terminator from all lines and it will fix your issue. Just add it at the start of your pipeline.

Comment: @jon: BTW you probably have extra trailing whitespace in one of those lines, before the '\r' (the ^M) character. Otherwise sort/uniq would have deemed it as part of the line and merged it successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two main causes for uniq failing to merge identical lines:

- The lines are not really identical - extra trailing whitespace is a usual suspect here. The awk commands should filter those in this example, but you can check that anyway. Mixed-up line terminators are also a possible cause.
- The lines are not adjacent - sort can and will fail to sort lines "properly" if the locale settings are incorrect. I *have* seen weird cases with non-ASCII text where identical lines will not end up one after the other. Check the output of sort, before the uniq command. What are your locale settings?

BTW, 'sort -u' is a better alternative for 'sort | uniq'.

EDIT:

Seems like one or both of these issues:

- You have mixed line-terminators. If some of your lines end up in LF (\n, Unix style terminators) and some in CR/LF (\r\n, DOS-style terminators), uniq will treat them as different lines, even if they are otherwise identical.
- Trailing whitespace in some of your lines along with CR/LF DOS-style line terminators. The CR (Carriage return, '\r') character is not considered whitespace by most (all?) unix utilities, including awk. If one of your lines does not have any other trailing whitespace, the CR will be considered part of its last field and be printed out. On the other hand, in a line with whitespace between the last field and the CR, the last field as printed by awk would not contain the CR.

Changing the CR/LF line terminator to LF will solve both issues in this case, although it's generally best to filter trailing whitespace as well:

- dos2unix is the preferred way
- As an alternative, filter your file through `sed 's|\r$||'`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have stray characters in your file. Clean it first using:

```
dos2unix your_file
```

Also, unrelated to your problem, but you can replace `sort | uniq` with simply `sort -u`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Removing whitespace, making sure all files were in UTF-8, nothing seemed to work. I was starting to pull my hair out. `do2unix` brought the salvation I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the command you specified in your question, but ran the following instead:

cat foo|cut -d \= -f 2|sort |uniq

where "foo" is a file containing the 2 lines in your example.
The output of the above is "moon1".

Simpler than your example because I assume that there is only one 'name=value' pair per line; I don't know anything about your file format.

Hope this helps anyway...

Comment: Your oneliner may be shorter but it treats trailing whitespace differently to the OP's awk commands.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a similar problem but in addition to removing duplicate lines I wanted to make sure that order of lines is also maintained. Combining uniq and sort defeats this purpose.

Luckily awk provides the solution

$ awk ‘!x[$0]++’ filename.txt

[awk and duplicate lines](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-removing-duplicate-lines/#comment-38830)